# NODEJS Create zip from byte string

Tags: node.js

I have to make a POST request to a server that returns me this.
[image]

And I have to write a ZIP from that, how do I get the bytes from that string to generate my zip file?

Comment: Show us your code.  But you just need to pipe it to a file.

Comment: yeah, you should pipe it to a file, as putting it on console tries to stringily it which results in these weird characters

Comment: Thanks, it was just that.

Answer (score 3):

you just need to create a buffer from the api response and create a zip file using that buffer.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var buff = new Buffer(response_from_api);
fs.writeFile("./test1.zip", buff, function(err){
    //do something
});
```

Comment: Hi Diwakar. Welcome to SO and thanks for your contribution. Please add explanation to your code so it can help the OP and future audience more than it is doing now.

Comment: explanation required.